# Optimize Mysql Table Structure to find duplicates

Tags: mysql

i am creating a url shortening site and need help in setting up the structure of the mysql table to optimize the table to find duplicate urls. Currently my structure is as follows:

```
id  int(10)
url  text
code  varchar(20)
date_added  datetime
```

Indexes on:

```
PRIMARY BTREE
code BTREE
```

I was thinking that i should add another field called domain, and then modify the sql statement to first match the url domain, and if any duplicates found, do another sql_query to search the url to find duplicates.

Thanks
*"Merry XMAS"*

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that can help you in locating the duplicates:

```
SELECT url,
 COUNT(url) AS NumOccurrences, id, code, date_added
FROM websites
GROUP BY url
HAVING ( COUNT(url) > 1 )
```